# Do-While clarification

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a Do-While loop in visual studio 2017.

```
        int k = 90;

        do
        {
            k = k - 1;
        } while (k == 5);


        Console.WriteLine(k);
```

Output 89

I have to change to k >= 5 so i can have the value I want. Did anyone know why the == does not work??

Comment: Can you please clarify your expectation on how `do`-`while` loop should work and [edit] the post. Make sure to provide links to supporting documentation.

Comment: I just got confused from another language with repeat until

Answer (score 0):

Because k is never equal to 5, so while loop runs only time, then continues to Console.WriteLine(k);

Comment: Thank you for your answer I just got confused from another language with repeat until